# Using the java BufferedRead in Matlab with an TCP/IP Ethernet connection - accessing the most recent data

Tags: java, xml, matlab, bufferedreader, ethernet

I am currently writing a MATLAB code to control instruments mounted on the end of a robotic arm. I am accessing the robot's positional data over a TCP/IP ethernet connection. The coms are working. The data is transmitted in XML file packets. I have written a parsing script to extract the correct data from the stream.

However, when I try to add more commands (for example to control the instruments) my code does not work correctly. The issue is that the buffer fills up with a certain (large) amount of data from the robot and when I call the `in.readLine` command, it reads the next line of the buffer, not the most recent line received over the connection. If the program has been busy doing other things (simulated by the `pause(0.01)` command, then the positional data displayed can be quite behind where the robot actually is. If the robot stays stationary, the data eventually catches up though. There is no command to flush a BufferedReader, and I cannot find a way of using the reset and mark commands to work as this seems to reset to an *earlier* string of data in the buffer. **Is there a way to access the most recent data in the buffer which is constantly being updated from the ethernet communications?**

I cannot delete the buffer and create a new one as this breaks the connection to the robot and causes its program to fail.

Apologies for the code below, it's a work in progress so excuse its rough-and-readiness. The code that is commented out using the mark and reset commands is just one attempt at using them I tried. I also tried playing around with the size of the buffer so it would constantly overflow and "flush" itself but even with the buffer size set to its smallest of 1, the problem still persisted.

```
clear all; close all; clc;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.System;

PORT = 6008;

try
    server_socket = ServerSocket(PORT);
    disp('Server started, awaiting connections...')

    client_socket = server_socket.accept;
    in = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream));

%    m = in.markSupported;
%     if(m == 1)
%         disp('Mark supported');
%     end
%    in.mark(8192);

    while 1
        XMLdata = in.readLine;                    %Reads the next line in the buffer
        [test, bin]=strtok(char(XMLdata));        %
         if strcmp(test, '<RIst') == 1            %Tests to see if it is a line with positional data
             rsi_parse                            %If so, parses the data into an array
%             in.reset;
%             in.mark(8192);
         end
         pause(0.01)                             %Pause to simulate other commands which cause the buffer to fill up
    end

catch
    disp('Error. Closing connection.')
    closeConnections(server_socket, client_socket, in);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using MATLAB's ability to run Java as a scripting language, which is a neat feature. While doing that you inherit MATLAB's "only" major limitation, it is single threaded. There are workarounds like timers, but at it's core there is only one thread.

In order the get the latest data from your robot, you seem to be forced to continuously read from the data stream. This can be achieved by creating a pure Java class that spans a thread, that continuously reads from your socket and updates a class property with the latest data. 
The Java class must be compiled using javac in order to generate a class file that can be instantiated as an object in MATLAB. Apart from a start and stop method it should provide a getLatestDate() method that's called from the MATLAB script in order to get the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the question is:  "how can I insure that I am reading the most recent data from my input stream, discarding data if needed".

If so, then you will want to expand your data ingestion portion of the code with an inner while loop:

```
    while 1
        %
        %  Read until we find the end of the buffer
        %
        XMLdata = in.readLine;  %Reset current line
        foundData = nan;        %Reset value found
        while ~isempty(XMLdata)                 %Loop to the end of the buffer
            [test, bin]=strtok(char(XMLdata));  %Line testing, as before
            if strcmp(test, '<RIst') == 1       
                foundData = rsi_parse           %Store the found data, we may get a more recent version
            end
            XMLdata = in.readLine;              %Try and read another line
        end
        %Do something with foundData

        %
        %Go and perform other work
        %
        pause(0.01)                             %Go and do something else
    end
```

---

Related to your comment that you cannot "purge" a BufferedReader, I think that you can, like this:

```
charactersSkipped = in.skip(1000000000);
```

(If you were writing directly in Java you should use `in.skip(java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE);`, but that breaks the Matlab/Java interface, and is sent to Java as a negative number, so you just need to pick the largest number you are comfortable typing.)

But after you have purged it there is no clear way to back up until you find the character pattern you are looking for.